# How to prevent my array to updated again and again on onChange Function in React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have cloned an array and I have an `onChange` function. On calling `onChange` function my original and cloned array is updating according to the updated onChange value. But I don't want to update my cloned array. How can I do this ?

My code -

```
const clonedArray = [...originalArray];

const onChange = (id:number, value: string): void => {
    const arrayData = originalArray;
    
    const selectedData = arrayData.find(
        (data) => data.myId === id
    );
    if (selectedData) {
        // updating my originalArray according to new changed value;
    }
}
```

this `onChange` function is also updating my `clonedArray`. I don't wanna update my `clonedArray`. How can I do this ? What is the solution useMemo or something ? Can anyone tell me the solution for it ?

Comment: Is originalArray , an array object?

Comment: @ankush Verma yes it is array of objects

Comment: is `originalArray` in state?

Comment: @Dimitar originalArray is in state

Comment: When you have an array of arrays or an array of objects, during cloning you only lose the surface level reference. The reference for array[1] still remains. You can try to convert the value to JSON back and forth in order to lose the reference

Comment: If updating `originalArray` is changing things elsewhere this is a red flag that you are mutating the array elements instead of updating them in new references. I suspect the mutation is somewhere in the code you omitted in `// updating my originalArray according to new changed value;`, which is oddly enough the most important part of the code you've an issue with. Please include all relevant code in your question.

Answer (score 1):

## Issue

This issue is state object/array mutation. You are mutating elements in an array and seeing the mutations manifest in a "copy".

Firstly, `const clonedArray = [...originalArray];` is only a shallow copy of the `originalArray`, not a clone. This means that other than the array reference itself, all the elements in `clonedArray` still refer to the same elements in `originalArray`.

Secondly, if later you are making changes in `originalArray` and you are seeing them manifest in `clonedArray` then you are definitely mutating the element references instead of creating ***new*** references.

## Solution

You are looking for the Immutable Update Pattern. When updating state in React it is necessary to shallow copy not only the root object/array that is being updated, but all nested state as well. To help with endeavor, especially when updating arrays, you will want to also use functional state updates so you can correctly update from the previous state.

For this I'm assuming (based on a comment that `originalArray` was in state) that your state looks something like this:

```
const [originalArray, setOriginalArray] = useState([]);
```

The change handler/state update (*just an example since I don't know your exact update requirements*)

```
const onChange = (id: number, value: string): void => {
  const selectedData = originalArray.find((data) => data.myId === id);

  if (selectedData) {
    // updating my originalArray according to new changed value
    // Array.prototype.map shallow copies the array into a new array reference
    setOriginalArray(originalArray => originalArray.map(data => data.myId === id
      ? {               // <-- updating element into new object reference
        ...data,        // <-- shallow copy previous data element
        property: value // <-- update property with new value
      }
      : data            // <-- not updating, pass previous object through
    );
  }
}
```

Once you are correctly updating the array elements, then no mutations will occur to anything that may also be referencing the state.

Answer (score 0):

you can use useMemo with empty dependency array. whenever originalArray updates, clonedArray doesn't change.

```
import { useMemo, useState } from "react";
const arr = [1,2,3]
export default function App() {
  const [originalArray, setOriginalArray] =  useState(arr)
  const clonedArray = useMemo(() => originalArray, [])
      
  return (
    <div className="App" style={{textAlign:'center'}}>
      originalArray: {originalArray}
      <br/>
      clonedArray:{clonedArray}
      <br/>
      <button onClick={() => setOriginalArray([1])}>update original</button>
    </div>
 );
```

}